# On duplicate Key update.. database key?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, pdo

I have a table `(id, name, price, menu_id)`

I have a page in which every item's name and price is shown, and the users can edit it.

But when I submit, it creates new rows.

The index is on the primary key. Should it be on something else?

I tried the following:

```
INSERT INTO gerechten 
SET gerecht_naam = :naam, gerecht_prijs = :prijs, menu_id = :menuid 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE gerecht_naam = :naam, gerecht_prijs = :prijs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query will transform to an update whenever any `unique key` crashes in your table. Up to you to decide where this key should be placed on. For example, your query could be:

```
INSERT INTO `gerechten` (`name`, `price`, `menu_id`) 
VALUES  (:name, :price, :menuid)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    name = :name, 
    price = :price
```

with a unique index on `name` **AND** `menu_id` for example. (I believe there can be several times the same name as long as it is in a different menu)

Of course if there are various fields combinations that must be unique this is a problematic situation and maybe you should use a different approach, such as a `select ... lock` statement to check previous existence of the values being edited.

Comment: Select lock is way out of my sql knowledge :( I didn't think something like this would be so difficult It's just a page that shows the current rows, the user can edit them or add new rows and then press save.

Comment: then your query might just do it perfectly, the thing is I don't understand the column names and I can't tell you really. Could you translate the column names?

Comment: INSERT INTO gerechten 
SET name = :name , price = :price, menu_id = :menuid 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE name = :name , price = :price

Comment: I put the primary key on 'id' but there is a unique on 'name' and 'price' .. i thought that would work. :) but it doesn't .

Comment: see my edit: the unique index should be on name and menuid instead (drop the old one)

Comment: Still adding a new row.. I don't get it. there is also a primary on id, and a index on menu_id to reference other table.. but that shouldn't matter right? ( thanks by the way )

Comment: No it does not matter. Could you show the result of the command `DESCRIBE gerechten` please¿?

Comment: gerecht_id  -- int(11) NO -- PRI -- NULL -- auto_increment
gerecht_naam -- varchar(160)-- NO -- MUL -- NULL 
gerecht_prijs -- float -- NO  -- NULL 
menu_id -- int(3)-- NO -- MUL -- NULL

Comment: are you sure the index is unique? It is impossible to insert twice the same set of values in that case.

Comment: Well the unique is on NAME & MENU_ID so if i change a name ( edit it ) it will make a new record with the new name..

Comment: yes that's why you have to pass the menuid from the form all the time! I think you should add a NOT NULL constraint to your columns.

Comment: hmh. this is what happens when i edit a row in on my page. i had row 'cat' and row 'dog'.. i change 'dog' to 'cow' and now it adds a row.. looks like this now  http://notflip.be/uploads/sebas2.jpg

Comment: Oh, you're changing the name? I understand your problem now. I think the only solution would be to pass the id to the form so when they edit it, they can pass it back to the php and you can decide to do an update if there's an id, or an insert when there's not.

Comment: I should do that with a hidden field or something then? allright! thank you so much! i'll try to figure this out. been trying everything for 4 hours straight now. thank you!

Comment: you're welcome! Open another topic here when you're done with coding your new solution and you have problems :)

Comment: how do i open a new topic here? :) thanks! i managed to get 3 arrays in POST now. Now i should find a way so they check which name and price doesn't have an id

Comment: it should be easier than that: whenever you get an ID from the form, you update. Otherwise you insert. If the unique clause crashes, it HAS to crash, and your user has to see the error, since you don't want them to have 2 similar entries by mistake.

Comment: Aha i understand. problem is it's a complicated structure ( there's 3 arrays, the ids , names and prices arrays.. no clue how to combine them.. or how to check this. damnit! i'm getting closer thanks to you! not giving up now :)

Comment: Oh, I don't know.. You could go for an ajax update for each items in the menu instead of saving the whole form at once. It would not change your php so much, just a little addition in the javascript (adding a save button in front of each row the users can edit, with onclick an asynchronous xmlhttp post request to your php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [UNIQUE key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/constraint-primary-key.html) to the `gerech_naam` column and/or to the `gerech_prijs` (you can have two columns define uniqueness of a row).

If you were to implement these unique keys to the table, you have to be aware that you would still have a problem because if you change the name or the price it could possibly `insert` in the DB because the data you provide doesn't exist in the table.

Comment: That's what i experienced! How could i make sure the user can change data and save it ? any ideas? thanks by the way

Comment: If you want to be able to change the name and the price in the same time, you will have to rely on another unique key (the primary key for example). Your URL could enclose the ID of the product (unless it's a new one), if there is an ID, you get the product from the DB and update its values otherwise you create a new one. If you want to add uniqueness put a unique key on the `gerech_naam`. On creation, either you check if the name already exists or check if the update/insert statement throws an exception by try/catching it.

Comment: I think i understand what you mean.. But it's difficult to translate it into a working thing. I'll try some more.. are there other methods of doing a if exists update?